# Android relative layout - align images to the right

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have the following layout: 
[image]

The layout is composed of 3 images  (Image1, Image2, Image3) and 
2 TextView (Text1 and Text2)
**Image2 and Image3 are optional**. 
The idea is to use a RelativeLayout with the following constraints:
- Text1 is to the right of image1 
- Text2 is to the right of image1 
- Text2 is below Text1 
- Image2 is to the right of Text1 (and aligned to the right) 
- Image3 is to the right of Text2 (and aligned to the right)

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Image1"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Text1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Text1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Text2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Issues**:
As for now I am not able to align Image2 and Image3 to the right.
How can I control the size of Image1 and Image2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add these lines

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

to your right images, Image2 and Image3.

Comment: This worked for me: 

android:adjustViewBounds="true"      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
android:alignParentRight="true"
```

for the image2 and image3

Comment: I get the processing error: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentRight' in package 'android'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code to achieve the above.

[image]

Change the Id's and background color accordingly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rghtImgOne"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rghtImgTwo"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/rghtImgOne"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:background="#00FFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtOne"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Try and encourage the user to try himself.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul will do hereafter.

Comment: You assumed that the images will have fixed dimensions.

Comment: Atleast i tried to help him,Never mind about the downvotes. I agree with Benjamin only. Sorry for the above answer.